# SQL - displaying the top selling european car model

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this question:

Display the details (i.e. Manufacturer name, model name, type) of the top selling European car
model.

the tables are:

**MANUFACTURER**

```
CREATE TABLE Manufacturer(
manufacturerID    VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL,
name     VARCHAR2(20),
region   VARCHAR2(20) CHECK(region IN('ASIA', 'AFRICA', 'NORTH AMERICA', 'SOUTH AMERICA', 'EUROPE', 'OCEANIA')),
PRIMARY KEY(manufacturerID));
```

**SALESTRANSACTION**

```
CREATE TABLE SalesTransaction(
VIN    VARCHAR2(17)  NOT NULL,
custID   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
agentID   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
dateOfSale DATE,
agreedPrice NUMBER(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY(VIN, custID, agentID),
FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES Car(VIN),
FOREIGN KEY(custID) REFERENCES Customer(custID),
FOREIGN KEY(agentID) REFERENCES SalesAgent(agentID));
```

**CAR**

```
CREATE TABLE Car(
VIN      VARCHAR2(17)  NOT NULL,
dateAcquired   DATE,
yearBuilt  NUMBER(4) CHECK(yearBuilt >1980),
purchasedPrice  NUMBER(10,2),
askingPrice NUMBER(10,2),
currentMileage NUMBER(7),
modelNo VARCHAR2(10),
PRIMARY KEY(VIN),
FOREIGN KEY(modelNo) REFERENCES Model(modelNo));
```

**MODEL**

```
CREATE TABLE Model(  
    modelNo      VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL,
    name   VARCHAR2(20),
    type VARCHAR2(20) CHECK(type IN('CONVERTIBLE', 'HYBRID', 'LUXURY', 'SUV', 'VAN', 'COUPE', 'SEDAN', 'WAGON', 'HATCH', 'SPORTS', 'ROADSTER')),
    previousModel VARCHAR2(10),
    manufacturerID VARCHAR2(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(modelNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(previousModel) REFERENCES Model(modelNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(manufacturerID) REFERENCES Manufacturer(manufacturerID));
```

So far i did this:

```
SELECT Manufacturer.name, Model.name, Model.type
FROM Manufacturer, Model, Car, SalesTransaction
WHERE Manufacturer.region = 'EUROPE' 
AND Model.modelNo = Car.modelNo 
AND SalesTransaction.VIN = Car.VIN
AND Model.manufacturerID = Manufacturer.manufacturerID;
```

I get all the cars but I want only the top selling european car. 
Should I use ORDER BY and rownum =1? If that is a possible way to do it, how do I do it? I am confused how to do it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (rownum is product specific.) Which result do you want if it's a tie? You need GROUP BY and SUM to calculate sales.

Comment: I would do something with max count sales_transaction group by model or something like that

Comment: if you could supply some test data i'd be happy to create a sqlfiddle and find a more specific query for your tables

Comment: how to justify top selling car i mean which table column

Comment: Im using Oracle

Sorry, I did a slight mistake on the title, it will be top selling car model.

Comment: @jarlh I don't know what is a tie.

Comment: A tie is two different cars both top selling.

Comment: Ok then both will be displayed

Comment: but it does not really matter, because the inserts i recieved did not have any ties.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the total sales by doing a `group by` and then order the results by using `order by`.

```
SELECT Manufacturer.name, Model.name, Model.type, sum(st.agreedPrice) total_sales
FROM Manufacturer, Model, Car, SalesTransaction st
WHERE Manufacturer.region = 'EUROPE' 
AND Model.modelNo = Car.modelNo 
AND SalesTransaction.VIN = Car.VIN
AND Model.manufacturerID = Manufacturer.manufacturerID
group by Manufacturer.name, Model.name, Model.type
order by sum(st.agreedPrice) desc; -- order desc is important
```

You can then select the first row by using rownum on top of this.

```
select * from (
    SELECT Manufacturer.name manufacturer_name, 
           Model.name model_name, 
           Model.type, 
           sum(st.agreedPrice) total_sales
    FROM Manufacturer, Model, Car, SalesTransaction st
    WHERE Manufacturer.region = 'EUROPE' 
    AND Model.modelNo = Car.modelNo 
    AND SalesTransaction.VIN = Car.VIN
    AND Model.manufacturerID = Manufacturer.manufacturerID
    group by Manufacturer.name, Model.name, Model.type
    order by sum(st.agreedPrice) desc -- order desc is important
) where rownum <= 1;
```

This is one way to acheieve it. There are related questions such as "What happens when to cars are tied for the first spot?" that you need to consider as well.

Based on your scenarios, you could consider using the oracle analytic functions such as rank() or row_number() as well.

[Oracle RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions141.htm#SQLRF00690)

[Oracle DENSE_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions052.htm#SQLRF00633)

[ORACLE ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Comment: Yeah i tried doing this. I keep getting the error "column ambigiously defined"

Comment: also i have to only display Manufacturer.name, Model.name, Model.type, not total sales.

Comment: @jarlh - +1.. I did think of it, but wanted to keep it simple to answer just the OP's question about how to use ROWNUM. I updated the answer now. Thanks!

Comment: @noobstudent - Changed the query to get rid of the "colum ambi..." error. I think you can tweak it to only show the columns you need :)

Comment: Thank you so much man! Yeah this is the part I was confused on. It is displaying correctly.